# Iterating through JS Array + Array Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a bit of a novice I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

The idea is for searchArray to loop through array values &properties. It takes the arguments (property, value). When I call the function I get a RefernencError saying that property(hostname) is undefined. Is there something wrong with browsingHistory[i].property?

```
function searchArray(property, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < browsingHistory.length; i++) {
        return value === browsingHistory[i].property;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is browsingHistory? Is this another array ?

Comment: yes, browsingHistory is an array. it has objects in it with specific properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`browsingHistory[i].property` means the value of the property called "property".

use `browsingHistory[i][property]` instead

---

Demo

```js
function searchArray(property, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
        return value === my_array[i][property];
    }
}


var my_array = [
  {
    x: "foo",
    y: "bar"
  },
  {
    x: "foooooo",
    y: "baaaaar"
  }
]


// should output "true" because my array contains an element with a 
// property named "x" and which value is "foo"
document.body.innerHTML = searchArray("x","foo");
```

Comment: I want it to point at the value of "property". 
basically I could check if the array has any objects with the host name : x

Comment: check my demo, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you!
I was doing basically the same thing but I was calling 
searchArray( x, foo)

didn't realise I needed to put it in speechmarks. I am curious as to why though

Comment: because without quotes it is interpreted as an undeclared variable

Answer (score 0):

If you using a variable as a property of any object, you can use with "**.**" syntax.You have to use it as array with that property (**like array indexes**).For example

```
var property = "name";
....
anyObject[property] // equals to anyObject['name'] or anyObject.name
```